# Account Register on ASP net core not registering user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hi I'm trying to make a website for my company and I'm trying to get user accounts to work however everytime I try to register a new user on the register page it does not create a user in the database. I have confirmed this multiple times by looking in the SSOX localDB. The website is written in asp dotnet core. The only modifications I have done to this after the authentication template is added a user column using Entity Framework code first, and have added the user input into forms and the controllers accordingly. I have also followed the tutorial on https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/accconfirm.html
to add account confirmation.

As dotnetcore asp is fairly new there is not many questions asked and I have searched for my problem on google and also on stack but have failed to find an answer to my problem. I have included my code for the Account Controller, Register View Model and Register View below.

If anybody knows of a solution I would be very greatful.

Account Controller Register code:

```
// GET: /Account/Register
            [HttpGet]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public IActionResult Register(string returnUrl = null)
            {
                ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
                return View();
            }

            //
            // POST: /Account/Register
            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
            {
                ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {

                        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                        // Send an email with this link
                        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.UserName, model.Email, "Confirm your account", $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
                        //Line commented to prevent user logging in without confirming account. //await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        _logger.LogInformation(3, $"User {user.Id} created a new account");
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                    AddErrors(result);
                }

                // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                return View(model);
            }
```

Here is my RegisterViewModel Code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MainSite.Models.AccountViewModels
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my Register View code:

```
@model RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="UserName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Comment: Did you get an error or some invalidation?

Comment: The `[Authorize]` attribute shouldn't be there. Put `[AllowAnonymous]` instead of it.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak this worked thank you, it seems that in my process of making the site accessible to only users I put one too extra [Authorize] tags ahahahah. And once I uncommented the email authentication code it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `[Authorize]` attribute with the `[AllowAnonymous]` one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and take out the email confirmation in your POST request and just leave the registration, see if that makes any differences in your process.

Also, you can check tutorials for ASP.NET MVC - Registration which are similar to what you have above. In my application, I am not using confirmation for registering users, because they do not have this ability and the link is not available on the website.

Comment: I tried this but I'm afraid it did not work. I even made it so that if result.succeeded returned false then I would output an error to a file. But there was no error when making an account. And my Connection to the database is working fine as I can add to my other table that stores information for clients through the website.

Comment: Right, then the connection to the database is successful.There is a good tutorial here, http://tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-identity-tutorial-user-login-and-registration/. Is pretty basic, but it should help you register your users. Try and add some System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ") to check if the variables you're using are correct and you can launch your application in Debug Mode to see what's happening in the background.